# How to add property to document during developing, but don't save to database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
VK_Accounts_schema.pre('init', function(doc) {
  doc.vk = new VK(doc.access_token);
  return doc;
})

VK_Accounts_schema.methods.get_API = function(cb) {
  console.log(this); // i can see property vk
  this.vk(...) // ERROR undefined!!!
}
```

I necessary need to add the vk exactly into the document, i do not need to save it to the database.

Comment: what kind of error it is exactly? "Undefined is not a function" or "vk is not a function"? Big difference.

Comment: TypeError: this.vk is not a function

Comment: Well, it's not a function, looks like. Why are you using it as one?

Comment: I add property vk in middleware init;

In console.log(this) -> i can see property vk with my function;
But console.log(this.vk) -> undefined;

Answer (score 1):

```
VK_Accounts_schema.methods.get_API = function(cb) {
  this.get('vk')(...) // success :)
}
```